# How to get local system timezone in ActionScript?

Tags: datetime, actionscript-3, apache-flex, timezone, flex4

I want to find the local system timezone using ActionScript 3, I have tried many ways but unable to get any solution which will give me the actual result like if I will select (UTC -8:00)Pacific Time then the result will come UTC -8:00 or (UTC -8:00)Pacific Time (Results in UTC time zone).

So if anyone know how to achieve this please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getTimezoneOffset` function of the `Date` object to get an offset from UTC for a particular date.  [Reference Here](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#getTimezoneOffset()).

Note that this offset may vary depending on the date provided.  In the US Pacific Time zone, UTC-8 is used in the winter, and UTC-7 is used in the summer when DST is in effect.

Note that that API is for an *offset* only.  There is no API in ActionScript that will give you the machine's local *time zone* ID, such as `America/Los_Angeles` (IANA) or `Pacific Standard Time` (Windows).  See "Time Zone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure if you do

```
var date:Date = new Date()
```

then date will be in local browser time